# c++ class library dynamic runtime allocation

Tags: c++, runtime, size, alloc

Suppose I' have an interface class

```
class foo_if_t {

};
```

, a first library `libfoo_orig.so` with class `foo_t` which inherits from `foo_if_t` and has the following code:

```
#include "foo_if.h"

class foo_t : public foo_if_t{
private:
    int res;
public:
    foo_t(){}
    virtual ~foo_t(){}
};
```

and a second library `libfoo_mod.so` with class `foo_t` redefined as follows:

```
#include "foo_if.h"

class foo_t : public foo_if_t{
private:
    int res[100];
public:
    foo_t() {
         for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
         res[i] = i;
    }
    virtual ~foo_t(){}
};
```

I create a symlink `libfoo.so --> libfoo_orig.so` and compile the following application

```
#include "foo_orig.h"

int main(){
    foo_if_t *foo_if = new foo_t();
    delete foo_if;
}
```

with `g++ -ggdb -O0 test.cpp -o test -L. -lfoo` (hence linking to libfoo.so).

*At this point* I change the symlink to target `libfoo_mod.so` and rerun the code. This will result in the following error:

```
*** Error in `./test': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000001ec9010 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What I believe it could be happening is that the constructor allocation of `foo_t` from library `foo_orig.so` eats a smaller chunk of heap than the one from `foo_mod.so`, so when `foo_mod.so` `foo_t` constructor is invoked, it dirties the heap memory beyond the allocation boundaries (hence corrupting the heap `next` chunk reference). This is telling me that the heap reservation is somehow pre-calculated at link time, whereas I thought it would be resolved dynamically at runtime, based on the actual constructor code invoked. Am I getting it wrong, and, if not, why is the produced output code behaving like this ?

As counter-proof test, I've wrapped `new foo_t()` invocation within an implementation of `static foo_it_t * foo_if_t::new_instance()` written for each library; invoking `new_instance` from the main code works right.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that your library code and the main program code have a different idea of the layout structure of `foo_t`. Even though they both recognise the existence of the type, they have both been compiled with a different version of the header that defines it. This is always going to lead to big trouble.

In your case, the trouble is caused by the fact that the actual memory allocation, performed by `new`, is compiled from the main program and so has one idea of what the size of the created object is. The constructor meanwhile, is compiled with the library code and has an entirely different idea of the underlying object size. So the main program creates an object on the heap that is `sizeof(foo_t)` - which is `sizeof(int)` from its point of view. The constructor, not knowing this, happily trounces memory up to 100 ints, thus corrupting the heap.

Basically you cannot 'cheat' in this way. If you change header files you should always recompile libraries that depend on this header, or face unpredictable trouble like this (obviously you're doing it intentionally in this case, but this can easily be done by accident too).